# Freezing UI Thread with AsyncTask

Tags: android

I'm trying to use an `AsyncTask` to download a file with a notification progress. Everything works fine (downloads in background thread), except whenever I add the code to update the progress bar through `publishProgress()`, it freezes the whole phone, until the download is finished and the notification shows "Download Completed".

I'm completely lost as to why this is the case, but I am maybe thinking it's along the lines of the `publishProgress((downloadedSize / totalSize) * 100)` that i'm using?

Anyways here is the `DownloadDataTask`:

```
    protected String doInBackground(RomDataSet... params) {
        try {

            // Download file here, all good

            //now, read through the input buffer and write the contents to the file
            while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
                //add the data in the buffer to the file in the file output stream (the file on the sd card
                fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                //add up the size so we know how much is downloaded
                downloadedSize += bufferLength;
                //this is where you would do something to report the prgress, like this maybe

                publishProgress((downloadedSize / totalSize) * 100);
            }
            //close the output stream when done
            fileOutput.close();

        //catch some possible errors...
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ListActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);

        // configure the notification
        notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_stat_rom, "Downloading Rom via RomGet", System
                .currentTimeMillis());
        notification.flags = notification.flags | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
        notification.contentView = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.layout_download);
        notification.contentIntent = pendingIntent;
        notification.contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.status_icon, R.drawable.icon_rom);
        notification.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.download_description, "Downloading");
        notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.download_progress, 100, 0, false);

        getApplicationContext();
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(43, notification);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        //notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.download_progress, 100, Math.round(progress[0]), false);
        notification.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.download_description, Integer.toString(progress[0]));
        // inform the progress bar of updates in progress
        notificationManager.notify(43, notification);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.download_progress, 100, 100, false);
        notification.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.download_description, "Done");
        notificationManager.notify(43, notification);
    }
```

I'm really stuck on this one - Any help would be appreciated. Cheers

```
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        if ((progress[0] - lastSize) > 5000) {
            lastSize = progress[0];
            notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.download_progress, totalSize, progress[0], false);
            //notification.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.download_description, Integer.toString(progress[0]));
            // inform the progress bar of updates in progress
            notificationManager.notify(43, notification);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps you're calling `publishProgress()` too often? How about saving the last value of `(downloadedSize / totalSize) * 100` in an integer and only calling `publishProgress()` when it's different from the previous value?

Comment: Great idea, except now it doesn't freeze, but gives me the following error (i've edited it to the main post)

Comment: You definitely need to include the rest of the code. There's no way we can tell why what is null and why without it. All you need to do to solve this is follow the stack trace carefully and make notes of what is happening.

Comment: Sorry, i've fixed that error that i posted. However, even if i try and update when the difference between the last update size and the current update size is 5000, it still freezes the phone (i'm assuming because it's updating so much). I have a sample of how i'm updating it above. I don't see why it's such a problem, will i have to decrease the update frequency?

Comment: Try running `publishProgress((downloadedSize / totalSize) * 100);` in the UI thread, only thing I can think of. Use `runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {` I can remember something like this happening to me, and this fixed it.

Comment: @Austin , that seems to make it a bit better, but it still lags hell and then freezes the phone haha! And besides, isn't `publishProgress` run on the UI thread anyways? I thought that was the whole point of `AsyncTask`

Comment: I didn't think it was on the same thread, as you also posted above "background thread", but I'm human, could easily be wrong. Bill seems to made a good suggestion, maybe all the progress updates are too much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a mod operator to only update on 5, 10 or 20 %.  You're calling onProgressUpdate() constantly during the download.

```
if (downloadedSize % (totalSize / 20) == 0) { // 20 updates every 5%, 10 every 10% and 5 every 20%, etc.
    publishProgress((downloadedSize / totalSize) * 100);
}
```

Comment: Cheers! Whilst your code didn't actually work in my case, I adapted it into my `publishProgress()` by checking if the `downloadedSize` since last notification update was bigger than 5% of `totalSize`. Works great now, cheers!

Comment: You point me in the right direction! Thank you so much! Have a cookie 

Comment: @jsw, can you please provide me the code that works for you