# asyncTask and progressDialog : Freeze

Tags: android, progress

please see my code .. and if you can, tell me why my progressDialog stopped when the function is halfway done in the background, the screen hangs (nothing is displayed, the logcat shows all logs i put in the background function).

Then, right before the end, the progressDialog starts animating again and closes after a couple seconds (the function is finished and the result is displayed normally)

```
public class changeWall extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer> {
        protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... urls) {
            int totalSize=0;
            try {

                 if(s.loadBoolean() == false)
                {
                     log("IF = false");
                     log("tempLogin = "+tempLogin);
                     log("tempPassword = "+tempPassword);
                     getNewResponse(tempLogin,tempPassword);
                if(needSave)
                {
                 s.saveBoolean(true);
                }

                }
                 else
                 { 
                if(s.loadLogin()==null)
                { 
                   getNewResponse(tempLogin,tempPassword);
                }else
                {
                    getNewResponse(s.loadLogin(),s.loadPassowrd());
                }
                 } 
                parser.setLol(0);

                parser.startParse(RESULT_STRING);

             log("end parse");
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                log("internet connection lost");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                log(" connection lost");
            }
            log("count = "+parser.getFacebookId(1));
            publishProgress();
            totalSize=1;
            log("end of start");
            return totalSize;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            log("wall click ON PROGRESS UPDATE");
            wall.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tabbuttonon);
            messages.setBackgroundResource(0);
            activity.setBackgroundResource(0);
            profile.setBackgroundResource(0);
            l1_1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tabbuttononleft);
            l1_2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tabbuttononright);
            l2_1.setBackgroundResource(0);
            l2_2.setBackgroundResource(0);
            l3_1.setBackgroundResource(0);
            l3_2.setBackgroundResource(0);
            l4_2.setBackgroundResource(0);
            l4_2.setBackgroundResource(0);
            wall.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            messages.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            profile.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            activity.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

            try {
                loadWall();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
               wallProgres.dismiss();
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
           if(result==1)
           {
               log("end WallChange");

           }
        }
    }
```

simple map as this showed :

```
----start progress(progress.show())
----start function
--- animation (progressDialog)
---animation(---)
---animation(---)
---FREEZ
---FREEZ(Function steel working normal, progressDialog in freeze mode)
---animation
---end function
---progress.dismis();//
```

similar problem i found here..(this problem = my problem but without download) [Freezing UI Thread with AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209701/freezing-ui-thread-with-asynctask)
Regards,Peter.

Comment: guys, wallChanges.dissmis() closed normal.. error not here, just maybe can't right describe this error. But screen on halfway work of function just freezes( log cat showed me: function worked normally) But progress in freezes mode( animation not running look like screenShot) and in end work of function - progress show again animation, and than closed. sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

It may not be correct but place

```
wallProgres.dismiss();
 in  onPostExecute rather than in onProgessUpdate method.
```

beacuse onProgressUpdate calls while running , but onPostExecute calls after execution.

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 1):

place this line `"wallProgres.dismiss()"` in `onPostExecute().`

```
   protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
               if(result==1)
               {
                   log("end WallChange");

               }
               if(wallProgress.isShowing())
                       wallProgres.dismiss();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

put this line

```
wallProgres.dismiss();
```

in onPostExecute() method

```
protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
           if(result==1)
           {
               log("end WallChange");
               wallProgres.dismiss();
           }
        }
```